In Android UWB, Does UWB Controller get RangingResult.RangingResultPeerDisconnected?
I'm working on adding reconnect logic when uwb is disconnected based on uwb sample app.
https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples/tree/main/UwbRanging
and i'm using mobile phones for both controller and controlee.
But the problem is controller doesn't get RangingResult.RangingResultPeerDisconnected when uwb is disconnected.
    override fun prepareSession() = channelFlow {
        val job = coroutineScope.launch {

            //nearby connection starts
            connector.start().collect { event ->
                when (event) {
                    //nearby connection succeed and found nearby device
                    is UwbOobEvent.UwbEndpointFound -> {
                        //make uwb session and ready for uwb ranging
                        val rangingEvents = processEndpointFound(event)
                        activeJobs[event.endpoint] =
                            launch {
                                //
                                rangingEvents.collectLatest {
                                    sendResult(it)
                                }
                            }
                    }
            ...
            ...
    }

    private suspend fun ProducerScope<EndpointEvents>.sendResult(result: RangingResult) {
        val endpoint =
            if (localAddresses.contains(result.device.address)) localEndpoint
            else remoteDeviceMap[result.device.address] ?: return
        when (result) {
            is RangingResult.RangingResultPosition ->
                trySend(EndpointEvents.PositionUpdated(endpoint, result.position))

            // This is the result that should be obtained when the UWB disconnects.
            is RangingResult.RangingResultPeerDisconnected -> {
                Log.e("##UwbSessionScopeImpl", "sendResult: peerDisconnected")
                connector.reconnectUwb()
                trySend(EndpointEvents.UwbDisconnected(endpoint))
            }
        }
    }

However, after a few failed attempts, the controller suddenly receives a RangingResult.RangingResultPeerDisconnected event. As a result, it seems to fall into an infinite loop of reconnecting and disconnecting on both the controller and the controlee sides.
Is the controller functioning correctly?
and i'm using
controller: samsung galaxy s23 ultra, android 13
controlee: samsung galaxy s22 ultra, android 14
androidx.core.uwb:uwb:1.0.0-alpha05

Note: given how new the Ultra Wide Band API is, please document which devices/OS versions/library versions are being used for testing.

Thank you for letting me know.
controller: samsung galaxy s23 ultra, android 13
controlee: samsung galaxy s22 ultra, android 14
androidx.core.uwb:uwb:1.0.0-alpha05
